# How to read changes to shared values caused by "sub" activity from main activity?

Tags: android, sdk, sharedpreferences

When the main activity starts the "sub" activity and the "sub" activity makes changes to the shared values and is then destroyed (e.g. using the back option on a phone), is there a direct way of reading the changes at this stage?

On searching this matter I could only find references to using intent.putExtras and intent.getExtras plus using a bundle object. Are these the only way of handling the information ?

I tried to read the preferences from shared preferences straight after the activity was called thinking that when it finished this would be the next part it would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the preferences in you onResume() for your main activity is the statergy I use.  It gets them in on startup or after the preferenceActivity has changes, or after any other activity that may of changed them.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Ifor , Now why didn't I think of that :) easy when you know how .

Comment: Sorry Ifor just tried your suggestion but on leaving the sub activity to return to the main, the change does not get applied. In fact on the first attempted change it is ignored but if I go into the sub activity and then leave it as is and come back out, it then changes. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorted this out now, I needed to use the onPause method to commit the changes made in the shared preferences instead I was using the onDestroy and also tried the onStop. This was all in the sub activity not the main.